# javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:""

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, unmarshalling

I am getting an exception while turning an XML response from a service to a POJO. The XML looks like this:

Here is my [XML response](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/Omnipresent/9513522/raw/30ee8d73dac96579f0f9a0f4f67ebb52aec26a42/response.xml).

```
javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:""
, local:"ItemSearchResponse"). Expected elements are
<{http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2011-08-01}ItemSearchResponse>
```

I am using it like this:

```
 Document response = getResponse(url);
 JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(AmazonItem.class);
 Unmarshaller unMarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller();
 newItem = (AmazonItem) unMarshaller.unmarshal(response);
```

Below are the details of my files

**package-info.java**

```
@XmlSchema(
        namespace = "http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2011-08-01",
        elementFormDefault = XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED)

package com.services.amazon;


import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema;
```

**AmazonItem.java**

```
@XmlRootElement(name="ItemSearchResponse")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class AmazonItem
{
    @XmlElement(name="Items")
    private Items items = null;
}
```

**Items.java**

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Items { 
    @XmlElement(name="Item")
    List<Item> items = new ArrayList();
}
```

**Item.java**

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Item {
    @XmlElement(name="ASIN")
    private String asin;

    @XmlElement(name="ItemAttributes")
    private ItemAttributes attributes;

    @XmlElement(name="ItemLinks")
    private List<ItemLinks> itemLinks;
}
```

**ItemAttributes.java**

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class ItemAttributes {
    @XmlElement(name="Title")
    private String title;

    @XmlElement(name="Actor")
    private List<String> actor;

    @XmlElement(name="ProductGroup")
    private String productGroup;
}
```

**ItemLink.java**

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class ItemLink {
    @XmlElement(name="Description")
    private String description;

    @XmlElement(name="URL")
    private String url;
}
```

**ItemLinks.java**

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class ItemLinks {
    @XmlElement(name="ItemLink")
    List<ItemLink> itemLinks;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

The error message is saying that you are getting an XML document that looks like this:

```
<ItemSearchResponse>
```

Instead of one like the following that matches the namespace qualification that you have mapped:

```
<ItemSearchResponse xmlns="http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2011-08-01">
```

Comment: hmmm but my xml does have a namespace qualification... as I posted. but you are right, if I remove the namespace from `package-info.java` then it works fine.

Comment: @Ethan - Is the `url` parameter in your code really set to https://gist.githubusercontent.com/Omnipresent/9513522/raw/30ee8d73dac96579f0f9a0f4f67ebb52aec26a42/response.xml or to something else?

Answer (score 4):

The explanation is [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/xml/bind/JAXBContext.html):
The JAXBContext instance is intialized with class(es) passed as parameter(s) and classes that are statically reachable from these class(es).

Initialize `JAXBContext` using package, so it can see `@XmlSchema` declared in package-info.java:

```
JAXBContext.newInstance("com.services.amazon")
```

Comment: It isn't required to bootstrap the `JAXBContext` on the package name to get the `@XmlSchema` annotation.  Currently according to the error message the JAXB is expecting the namespace, it is the XML that appears to be missing it.

Comment: Can be, then author should check the input, the one that he provided does have namespace

Answer (score 3):

If you're using DocumentBuilderFactory in your getResponse method, try setting namespace awareness:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
```

I had the same UnmarshalException and this solved it.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the namespace from `package-info.java` and change

```
elementFormDefault = javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED
```

to

```
elementFormDefault = javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm.UNQUALIFIED.
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the namespace from package-info.java 
It's work for me

Ex:

```
@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema(namespace = "", elementFormDefault = javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED)
```